# How does GNU GPL work in a fullstack Android project?

Tags: gpl, license-compatibility, android, license

1. What is the compatibility in terms of license with an API? For example: GPL license from the client side and PHP license from the server side, is it possible?
2. Can the Android application contain integrated payments?

Comment: What are the licenses in question? GPL from the client side and "PHP" from the server side -- PHP is a programming language, not a license. Of course PHP itself has a license, but any software you are running with PHP will have its own license, unless you wrote all of it yourself.

Comment: @Brandin Yes I was referring to the PHP license in one repository and the GPL license in another

Answer (score 2):

### Question 1

If the client application and the server application are in different repositories, both **can have any type of license that will be compatible** because the communication of the applications in a web service is through the network.

Different happens when using code we import libraries from external repositories, where before using a repository you have to check what can be done and not with a license.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the compatibility in terms of license with an API? For example: GPL license from the client side and PHP license from the server side, is it possible?

If you are talking about a web-API, then the provider and consumer of the API are generally considered to be independent works. This means that the license of the one does not affect in any way the license choices for the other one.

> Can the Android application contain integrated payments?

Yes, it can, but if you distribute the application under an open-source license then you are also giving the people that have a copy of the sources the rights to re-distribute the application without the payments but with otherwise the same functionality.
You will have to decide if it makes economic sense to add the payment options to an open-source application.